# Create image of the vm behind a scaleset in azure

Tags: image, azure, virtual-machine

I would like to take the image of the VM running in the scaleset in Azure. There is only 1 machine running in the scaleset and I would like to take the image of the same and then change the image ref in the scaleset. How can I do so using the portal. Not able to see the option neither in the Azure documents not somewhere else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I know, you only can capture an image from the VM, not the VMSS. No matter the portal or other ways.

To create an image from the VMSS, you can use the PowerShell or the CLI, but you also need to create a VM and then capture the image from it. The steps here:

1. Create a snapshot from the VMSS instance:

```
    $snapshotconfig = New-AzSnapshotConfig -Location $location -AccountType Standard_LRS -OsType Linux -CreateOption Copy -SourceUri $vmss1.StorageProfile.OsDisk.ManagedDisk.id
```

2. Create an OS disk from the snapshot:

```
    $snapshot = Get-AzSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $rgname -SnapshotName $snapshotName 

    $diskConfig = New-AzDiskConfig -AccountType Premium_LRS -Location $location -CreateOption Copy -SourceResourceId $snapshot.Id

    $osDisk = New-AzDisk -Disk $diskConfig -ResourceGroupName $rgname -DiskName ($snapshotName + '_Disk')
```

3. Create a VM from the managed disk:

   Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/create-vm-specialized-portal
4. Create a managed image of the VM in the portal:

   Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource

Comment: Thanks Charles, I will try this.

Comment: @Nipun Please let me know if you finish the try.

Comment: @Nipun Do you try the solution and does it solve your problem?

Comment: I am really sorry, could not find time to try it out.

Comment: @Nipun This is really a disturbing thing.

Comment: @Nipun That's great. Cheers!

Comment: Great! Microsoft should add this to their documentation.